# webpush notifications expiration

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox

I want to implement push notifications to my website. I set up the service worker and the push
api

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((serviceWorkerRegistration) => {
    serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager
        .subscribe({
            userVisibleOnly: true,
            applicationServerKey: <vapidPublicKey>
        });
});
```

And I can receive the subscription ID through

```
serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription()
.then((subscription) => {
    console.log(subscription);
});
```

If I want to host a custom server via `VAPID` and not use GCM (Google cloud messaging), 
I'm supposed to send the `subscription` object to my push server then use
a webpush library to send the notification by supplying the subcription ID(s)

However, do the subscription IDs have an expiration, or does a subscription expire only when a user wants to unsubscribe?

Comment: You can see here a full explanation of how to handle `pushsubscriptionchange` event. [How to handle WebPush API PushSubscriptionChange event in modern browsers](https://medium.com/@madridserginho/how-to-handle-webpush-api-pushsubscriptionchange-event-in-modern-browsers-6e47840d756f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and found that you can listen to the "pushsubscriptionchange" event  which is fired when subscription expires. Subscribe again and register the new subscription in the server by sending a POST request with endpoint. Real world application would probably use also user identification.

[Resource](https://serviceworke.rs/push-subscription-management_service-worker_doc.html)

Hope this help.

Comment: the problem is that Chrome does not support this event :/